# Models not showing up in django admin

Tags: python, django

I've already read all the questions here, but mine is special.

I've moved my `admin.py` file to a folder named "`admin`":

```
admin
+-- __init__.py
|
+-- generic.py
|
+-- admin.py
```

and `__init__.py` is empty.

in `admin.py` I have this declaration which *seems* not to be called:

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = _("Battlesoop's administration")

admin.site.register(Game, GameAdmin)
admin.site.register(Personne)
admin.site.register(PersonGameStats)
admin.site.register(PersonGame, PersonGameAdmin)
```

I say it *seems* not to be called because when I log in as a super user, I have access to `Group` and `User` models...

What am I missing?

Comment: As usual I always think that downvotes should be justified like "close" votes.

Comment: It looks like you are registering your models with the regular admin site, not your custom `MyAdminSite`, but it would be better to deal with that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your `admin/admin.py` somewhere, so that the `admin.site.register()` commands run. You could do this in your `admin/__init__.py`:

```
from . import admin
```

Comment: Got my relative import syntax mixed up. Try `from . import admin`.

Comment: You were right, this is working! Thanks a lot, even though I don't handle imports yet...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `admin.py` inside you django app not elsewhere.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Comment: When you create a folder `admin` that has `__init.py__` in it, it can replace your `admin.py` file, this is how python works....